# ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, jdbc, jtds

I have java code which connects to a MS-SQL database and procures some data.

Before running the code I set the class path in the Unix Server and it used to work fine.

But for some reason the same jar file which was working a few days back is throwing a Class not found exception **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver**

I have un-jared the jar file and found that the driver class which I'm loading :

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
```

is present in the specified package structure.

I don't understand how this is happening.

Can anyone suggest any tips to resolve this.

Comment: Is it possible that you have another version of that jar?

Comment: This is happening because you don't have the driver's JAR on the classpath. Perhaps the people who administer the server moved it. We can't answer that for you.

Comment: No is the same jar file that I used before and prior to running the java code I add the jar to the classpath "setenv CLASSPATH ${CLASSPATH}:/app/config/usr/admin//jar_test/test2/jtds_conn/jtds-1.2.7.jar"

Comment: And the jar file is at the same location as it was before. I have never faced such an issue before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue of **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException** might be the outcome of several reasons:

- Jar file is not available in class path. (This is not your case. as
  you have mentioned).
- Your jar file is corrupted.
- Your environment variable value is not accessible by current user. 
  (Permission revoked by  administrator).
- Current user don't have permission to read jar file.

Please verify the last three options.

Answer (score 2):

Right button on project-> Properties - > Java built Path -> Order and Export -> And check checkBox with you jar.

If you connect on Android project to Use 1.2.7 version.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late, but for others facing the same problem..

If you are using eclipse:
**1. Go to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and export.. and check the jar file for jtds.version.jar**

**2. Go to Run Configurations and add this jar file to the user defined jars.** 

Hope this helps..:)