# NoClassDefFoundError when loading jtds driver in Android

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, jtds

I am frustrated.....`Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance()` keeps giving the error. strange, but in the following code, a call to `gaConnecion.setConnection` from MainActivity works fine! but from ResultsActivity it fails with the above error:

gaConnection.java:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class gaConnection 
{
    String url ="";
    Connection conn=null;
    Statement statement=null;
    ResultSet resultSet=null;
    public void setConnection(String DBName,String UserName,String Password, Context  context)
{
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        url ="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://212.150.9.60:1433;instanceName=MSSQLServer;DatabaseName="+DBName+";integratedSecurity=true;user="+UserName+";password="+Password;
        conn =DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();                
            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}

public String showResult()
{
    String strResult="";
    try
    {
        statement=conn.createStatement();
        resultSet=statement.executeQuery("select * from vehicles where number='4195666'");
        while(resultSet.next()){
           strResult = strResult + " Name : "+resultSet.getString(1)+"  SirName : "+resultSet.getString(2) + "\n";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return strResult;
}

public void storeInfo(String text) {
    String dateStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy").format(new Date());
    String hourStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss").format(new Date());
    try
    {
        statement=conn.createStatement();
        resultSet=statement.executeQuery("insert into vehicles(number, date, time) values('" + text + "', '" + dateStamp + "', '" + hourStamp + "')");           
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

ResultsActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ResultsActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);

    getResultsFromSQL();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.results, menu);
    return true;
}

public void getResultsFromSQL() {
    String DBName="hofyam";
    String UserName="sa";
    String Password="sadmin";
    TextView tvData=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textSQLResults);

    try {gaConnection c=new gaConnection();
        c.setConnection(DBName,UserName,Password, getApplicationContext());
        tvData.setText(c.showResult());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        tvData.setText(e.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

logcat:

```
01-13 10:43:26.444: V/Provider/Setting(31537): invalidate [system]: current 171 != cached 0
01-13 10:43:26.447: V/Provider/Setting(31537): from db cache, name = sound_effects_enabled value = 0
01-13 10:43:26.448: I/fengjun1010(31537): -----startActivityForResult,intent=Intent { cmp=com.example.hofyam/.ResultsActivity (has extras) }
01-13 10:43:26.449: I/fengjun1010(31537): -----agoldPhoneStateListener-----
01-13 10:43:26.449: I/fengjun1010(31537): ----------mPhoneListenerFlag=true
01-13 10:43:26.449: I/fengjun1010(31537): ------------agoldChangeGoodleStoreApp---------
01-13 10:43:26.449: I/fengjun1010(31537): -------------------mChangeFlag=false
01-13 10:43:26.449: I/fengjun1010(31537): ----startActivity---,intent=Intent { cmp=com.example.hofyam/.ResultsActivity (has extras) }
01-13 10:43:26.450: I/fengjun1010(31537): ---ComponentInfo{com.example.hofyam/com.example.hofyam.ResultsActivity}
01-13 10:43:26.478: D/ActivityThread(31537): ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{41623298 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41621218 {com.example.hofyam/com.example.hofyam.MainActivity}}
01-13 10:43:26.504: D/ActivityThread(31537): ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@41621218
01-13 10:43:26.508: I/fengjun1010(31537): -----agoldPhoneStateListener-----
01-13 10:43:26.508: I/fengjun1010(31537): ----------mPhoneListenerFlag=true
01-13 10:43:26.630: D/NativeCrypto(31537): NativeCrypto_EVP_VerifyInit ctx=0x52c0c020
01-13 10:43:26.631: D/NativeCrypto(31537): NativeCrypto_EVP_VerifyInit algorithmChars=RSA-SHA1
01-13 10:43:26.729: I/System.out(31537): [CDS]connect[/212.150.9.60:1433] tm:90
01-13 10:43:26.730: W/System.err(31537): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-13 10:43:26.758: W/System.err(31537):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1125)
01-13 10:43:26.758: W/System.err(31537):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
01-13 10:43:26.758: W/System.err(31537):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:159)
01-13 10:43:26.758: W/System.err(31537):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
01-13 10:43:26.759: W/System.err(31537):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
01-13 10:43:26.759: W/System.err(31537):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
01-13 10:43:26.759: W/System.err(31537):    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:575)
01-13 10:43:26.760: W/System.err(31537):    at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:130)
01-13 10:43:26.760: W/System.err(31537):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:180)
01-13 10:43:26.761: W/System.err(31537):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:152)
01-13 10:43:26.761: W/System.err(31537):    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.<init>(SharedSocket.java:252)
01-13 10:43:26.762: W/System.err(31537):    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:297)
01-13 10:43:26.762: W/System.err(31537):    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:181)
01-13 10:43:26.762: W/System.err(31537):    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:175)
01-13 10:43:26.763: W/System.err(31537):    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:140)
01-13 10:43:26.763: W/System.err(31537):    at com.example.hofyam.gaConnection.setConnection(gaConnection.java:24)
01-13 10:43:26.764: W/System.err(31537):    at com.example.hofyam.ResultsActivity.getResultsFromSQL(ResultsActivity.java:32)
01-13 10:43:26.764: W/System.err(31537):    at com.example.hofyam.ResultsActivity.onCreate(ResultsActivity.java:15)
01-13 10:43:26.765: W/System.err(31537):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5158)
01-13 10:43:26.765: W/System.err(31537):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-13 10:43:26.766: W/System.err(31537):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
01-13 10:43:26.767: W/System.err(31537):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
01-13 10:43:26.768: W/System.err(31537):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
01-13 10:43:26.769: W/System.err(31537):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
01-13 10:43:26.769: W/System.err(31537):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-13 10:43:26.770: W/System.err(31537):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
01-13 10:43:26.770: W/System.err(31537):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
01-13 10:43:26.770: W/System.err(31537):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 10:43:26.771: W/System.err(31537):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-13 10:43:26.772: W/System.err(31537):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
01-13 10:43:26.772: W/System.err(31537):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
01-13 10:43:26.772: W/System.err(31537):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 10:43:26.816: W/System.err(31537): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-13 10:43:26.817: W/System.err(31537):    at com.example.hofyam.gaConnection.showResult(gaConnection.java:36)
01-13 10:43:26.817: W/System.err(31537):    at com.example.hofyam.ResultsActivity.getResultsFromSQL(ResultsActivity.java:33)
01-13 10:43:26.817: W/System.err(31537):    at com.example.hofyam.ResultsActivity.onCreate(ResultsActivity.java:15)
01-13 10:43:26.817: W/System.err(31537):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5158)
01-13 10:43:26.817: W/System.err(31537):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-13 10:43:26.817: W/System.err(31537):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
01-13 10:43:26.818: W/System.err(31537):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
01-13 10:43:26.818: W/System.err(31537):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
01-13 10:43:26.818: W/System.err(31537):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
01-13 10:43:26.818: W/System.err(31537):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-13 10:43:26.818: W/System.err(31537):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
01-13 10:43:26.818: W/System.err(31537):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
01-13 10:43:26.818: W/System.err(31537):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 10:43:26.818: W/System.err(31537):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-13 10:43:26.818: W/System.err(31537):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
01-13 10:43:26.819: W/System.err(31537):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
01-13 10:43:26.819: W/System.err(31537):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 10:43:26.819: D/ActivityThread(31537): ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{4166e1d8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4166d9d8 {com.example.hofyam/com.example.hofyam.ResultsActivity}}
01-13 10:43:26.822: D/ActivityThread(31537): ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{4166e1d8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4166d9d8 {com.example.hofyam/com.example.hofyam.ResultsActivity}}
01-13 10:43:26.823: V/InputMethodManager(31537): focusOut: android.widget.EditText@4163f570 mServedView=android.widget.EditText@4163f570 winFocus=false
01-13 10:43:26.841: I/SurfaceTextureClient(31537): [void android::SurfaceTextureClient::init()] debug.stc.fps: 3000 ms
01-13 10:43:26.872: I/SurfaceTextureClient(31537): [void android::SurfaceTextureClient::init()] debug.stc.fps: 3000 ms
01-13 10:43:26.876: V/InputMethodManager(31537): onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#1810100
01-13 10:43:26.876: V/InputMethodManager(31537): Starting input: view=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4166f280
01-13 10:43:26.876: V/InputMethodManager(31537): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@416cefe0 ic=null
01-13 10:43:26.877: V/InputMethodManager(31537): START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4166f280 ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@416cefe0 controlFlags=#104
01-13 10:43:26.879: V/InputMethodManager(31537): Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy@416cfb70 com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME #1581}
01-13 10:43:26.934: D/OpenGLRenderer(31537): Flushing caches (mode 0)
01-13 10:43:26.960: I/SurfaceTextureClient(31537): [void android::SurfaceTextureClient::init()] debug.stc.fps: 3000 ms
01-13 10:43:26.972: D/ActivityThread(31537): ACT-STOP_ACTIVITY_HIDE handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@41621218
```

I tried a few jtds driver versions: 1.3.1, 1.2, 1.2.5, 1.2.7, nothing seems to solve the problem.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: can you show the logcat error?

Comment: posted the logcat. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. posting it for the sake of other folks....
After trying `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);`
,I realized I had to start network connection off the main thread. so I'll use `ASyncTask` to start the connection to the SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds environmental:

Have you tried this?

Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and export.. and check the jar file for jtds.version.jar 
Then go to Run Configurations and add this jar file to the user defined jars?

Source: [stackoverflow.com/questions/18658886](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658886)

Comment: Thank you Jake, but I'm a noob in android and eclipse. can you direct me how to add the jar to the user defined jars?

Comment: jtds jar is in Java build path-libraries, if that's what you meant.

Comment: Hi yes sure make sure the library is in your lib folder. 
Then go to Window --> Preferences --> Java Build Path --> Libraries --> Add JARs  and add them from your lib folder to the build path

Here is a good example: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)

Comment: I repeat.....this is very strange to me. the driver actually works fine when I call it from MainActivity, but not from ResultsActivity...

Comment: Yes go to Run configuration and add -jar [jar name].jar in VM arguments

Comment: Thank you Jake for helping. I found the root of problem.