# android app connects to external database

Tags: java, android, sql-server, jtds

I have tried whole nigh to connect my android app to MSSQL server with jtds-1.3.1.
Here is my Connection manager code. It works good on java console application..

```
package com.pjx.gradebook.dao;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionManager {


    public static void  query()     // it is triggered by a button click
    {
        Connection conn = null;
        try  
        {  
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");  
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ipaddress:1433/database;tds=8.0;lastupdatecount=true", username, password);  
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)  
        {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (SQLException e)  
        {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } 
    }

}
```

And I always get the error

```
05-22 06:47:42.230: W/System.err(21996): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
05-22 06:47:42.230: W/System.err(21996):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
05-22 06:47:42.230: W/System.err(21996):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
05-22 06:47:42.230: W/System.err(21996):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
05-22 06:47:42.230: W/System.err(21996):    at com.pjx.gradebook.dao.ConnectionManager.query2(ConnectionManager.java:19)
05-22 06:47:42.230: W/System.err(21996):    at com.pjx.gradebook.MainActivity.connect(MainActivity.java:44)
05-22 06:47:42.230: W/System.err(21996):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 06:47:42.230: W/System.err(21996):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-22 06:47:42.230: W/System.err(21996):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
05-22 06:47:42.230: W/System.err(21996):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
05-22 06:47:42.230: W/System.err(21996):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
05-22 06:47:42.230: W/System.err(21996):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-22 06:47:42.230: W/System.err(21996):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-22 06:47:42.230: W/System.err(21996):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-22 06:47:42.230: W/System.err(21996):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-22 06:47:42.230: W/System.err(21996):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 06:47:42.240: W/System.err(21996):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-22 06:47:42.240: W/System.err(21996):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-22 06:47:42.240: W/System.err(21996):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-22 06:47:42.240: W/System.err(21996):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 06:47:42.240: W/System.err(21996): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/Driver
05-22 06:47:42.240: W/System.err(21996):    ... 19 more
05-22 06:47:42.240: W/System.err(21996): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.pjx.gradebook-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.pjx.gradebook-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
05-22 06:47:42.240: W/System.err(21996):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
05-22 06:47:42.240: W/System.err(21996):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
05-22 06:47:42.240: W/System.err(21996):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
05-22 06:47:42.240: W/System.err(21996):    ... 19 more
```

Can any please help me?
ADT: Build: v22.6.2-1085508

Thank you!

Comment: Seems like you are missing the net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver depndency

Comment: Thank you. Bur how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer, if the error still persists I will try to find more solutions

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18660514/2721515